# Reading a binary file containing periodic samples

Tags: python, performance, file, numpy, serialization

I have the following code for reading [HTK](http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/) feature files. The code below is working completely correct (verified it with unit tests and the output of the original HTK toolkit).

```
from HTK_model import FLOAT_TYPE
from numpy import array
from struct import unpack

def feature_reader(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as in_f:
        #There are four standard headers. Sample period is not used
        num_samples = unpack('>i', in_f.read(4))[0]
        sample_period = unpack('>i', in_f.read(4))[0]
        sample_size = unpack('>h', in_f.read(2))[0]
        param_kind = unpack('>h', in_f.read(2))[0]

        compressed = bool(param_kind & 02000)

        #If compression is used, two matrices are defined. In that case the values are shorts, and the real values are:
        # (x+B)/A
        A = B = 0
        if compressed:
            A = array([unpack('>f',in_f.read(4))[0] for _ in xrange(sample_size/2)], dtype=FLOAT_TYPE)
            B = array([unpack('>f',in_f.read(4))[0] for _ in xrange(sample_size/2)], dtype=FLOAT_TYPE)
            #The first 4 samples were the matrices
            num_samples -= 4

        for _ in xrange(0,num_samples):
            if compressed:
                yield ((array( unpack('>' + ('h' * (sample_size//2)),in_f.read(sample_size)) ,dtype=FLOAT_TYPE) + B) / A)
            else:
                yield (array( unpack('>' + ('f' * (sample_size//4)),in_f.read(sample_size)), dtype=FLOAT_TYPE))
```

How can I speed up this code, are there things I should improve in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    data = in_f.read(12)
    num_samples, sample_period, sample_size, param_kind = unpack('>iihh', data)
    A = B = 0
    if compressed:
        A = array('f')
        A.fromfile(in_f, sample_size/2)
        B = array('f')
        B.fromfile(in_f, sample_size/2)
        #The first 4 samples were the matrices
        num_samples -= 4
```

And so on